# Relationship between bitwise XOR and the equations

Tags: mathematica

I am studying bitwise XOR.

If a, b, c are integers ranging from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, I belive the following work for both $=$ and $\neq$:

$1.\forall a,b,c(a=b\to a \oplus c=b \oplus c)$

$2.\forall a,b,c(a \oplus c=b \oplus c\to a=b)$

$3.\forall a,b,c(a\neq b\to a \oplus c\neq b \oplus c)$

$4.\forall a,b,c(a\oplus c\neq b\oplus c\to a\neq b)$

But the above will not work for $<, \le, >, \ge$.

Is that correct?

Comment: What are $a, b, c$? What operations or relations denote "$^$" and "$!=$"?

Comment: yes, (1)-(4) are correct and above doesn't work for inequalities. @AlexRavsky In some compute languages (eg. C), `^` and `!=` stands for bitwise XOR and numerical not-equal.

Comment: Since $a,b,c$ are integers, when you say "XOR" do you actually mean _bitwise_ exclusive OR? In Mathematica (the tag on this question), that would be BitXor rather than Xor. On the other hand, your use of the symbol `^` in the original version of the question suggests you were thinking of C or some other language that is not Mathematica--so it's unclear what the purpose of the Mathematica tag is.

Comment: @DavidK, sorry for the confusion. Yes, it is bitwise XOR. What is the difference between bitwise XOR and XOR? I think they are the same?

Comment: XOR naturally works with logical values, not integers. You have to make some interpretation of what an integer means as input to XOR. In Excel, for example, `1+XOR(8,7)` will give the result $1$, whereas if it were a bitwise XOR the result should be $16.$ What makes the difference is that $8$ and $7$ are both treated as "true" logical values by the (non-bitwise) XOR function, so you get the same result from `XOR(8,7)` as from `XOR(1,1)`.

Comment: @DavidK, Thank you for your explanation. I understand now. For XOR, there is only two kinds of logic values, zero(FALSE) and non-zero(TRUE). But for bitwise XOR, the XOR is performed on each bit one by one.

Comment: More briefly you just have one equation: $\forall {a,b,c} \left(a=b \iff a\oplus c = b\oplus c\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For equality:

Statement $(1)$ is true.

Statement $(2)$ is true since if $a\oplus c = b \oplus c$ then we have $(a \oplus c)\oplus c = (b \oplus c) \oplus c$, using the associative property, we have

$$a \oplus (c \oplus c) = b \oplus (c \oplus c)$$

$$a  = b$$

$(3)$ is true since $(2)$ an $(3)$ are equivalent.

$(1)$ and $(4)$ are equivalent, hence $(4)$ is correct as well.

---

It doesn't work on inequalities. To see counterexamples, choose $0$ to be the smaller element and pick $1$ to be the bigger element, picking $c=0$ would preserve the inequalities but picking $c=1$ would switch the direction of the inequalities.

For example.

- Conjecture: if $\forall a, b, c , a < b$ then $a \oplus c < b \oplus c $.

This is false since 
$0 < 1$, but $0 \oplus 1 = 1$ and $1 \oplus 1 = 0$.

Comment: Why statement (1) is true? Thank you.

Comment: if we have $a=b$, it implies that $f(a)=f(b)$ right? that is if $a$ and $b$ are the same, if you perform the same operation on them, you should get the same result.